# Add custom validation message to enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, enums

Is it possible to add a custom message to an enum if validation fails?

I have this enum class:

```
public enum EngineType{
  FOO('F'),
  BAR('B'),
  QUX('Q');
  private char id;

  EngineType(char id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public char getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

My model class contains `private MyEnum myEnum;`.

Currently if a value is passed in which isn't a valid enum, I get this BindingException:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "validationErrors": {
        "myEnum": "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ie.aviva.services.motor.cartellservice.model.EngineType' for property 'myEnum'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull ie.aviva.services.motor.cartellservice.model.EngineType] for value 'corge';"
    },
    "title": "Bad Request"
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      value = Endpoints.TRUE_MATCH,
      produces = {"application/json"})
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<List<TrueMatch>>> getTrueMatch(
      @Valid MyDetails MyDetails) {

    LogContext.put(Constants.TAG, myDetails);
    LOG.info(
        "Controller called to get true match with my details: " + myDetails.toString());
    ...
}
```

MyDetails is like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class MyDetails extends BasicDetails {

  @NotBlank
  @Pattern(
      regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]*$",
      message = "'${validatedValue}' contains unsupported characters")
  private String name;

  @NotNull private MyEnum myEnum;
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to change the message to some custom message of my own?

I'm already able to do this in annotations that I added to other variables by including the `message` parameter in the annotation. I tried creating an annotation to validate the pattern as seen [here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums) but it didn't work. I think because the annotation was added like this, which was too late. The exception had already been thrown:

```
@NotNull
@EnumNamePattern(regexp = "foo|bar|qux")
private MyEnum myEnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The simplistic solution would be to simply accept the value as a String, then wrap your parsing logic in a try-catch block, then return the result you want the user to see.

```java
final MyEnum userValue;

try
{

    userValue = MyEnum.valueOf(someStringInput);

}

catch (Exception e)
{

    //respond to the user, either with an exception, or
    //a proper response according to your application

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bean Validation & ControllerAdvice

You can make use of the [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) and [Exception-handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice) mechanisms provided by spring.

**Note** that OP is already using *Bean validation* in their project, which can be observed by the usage of annotations `@NotBlank`, `@Pattern`. So the following reference is exclusively for the Readers.

To include the *Bean validation* into your Spring Boot project, you can add [*Spring Boot Starter Validation dependency*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation). In a nutshell, Bean validation is a specification (like for instance JPA) describing an IPA, which offers various annotations and interfaces for verifying that the data of domain objects is correct. And *Hibernate Validator* is an implementation of this specification which comes with *Spring Boot Starter Validation*.

To validate that the given `String` matches one of the `enum`-constants we would need a separate class, let's say `MyDetailsDto`. In case if you wonder why a new class? If the validation constant would be applied on the field of type `enum` it would validate only input that can be successfully parsed into an `enum` (otherwise an `IllegalArgumentException` would be thrown before applying the validation annotation), which can be useful only certain enum-constants can be assigned to a field. But that's not the case, we need to find out whether the given string is equal to one of the enum constants (*by the way, in addition this approach creates an opportunity for sanitizing the input, for instance replacing some characters if needed*).

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyDetailsDto {
    private String name;
    @EngineTypeConstraint
    private String engineType;
    
    public MyDetails toMyDetails() {
        return new MyDetails(name, EngineType.valueOf(engineType));
    }
}
```

So, to create a custom *Validation constraint*, we need two things: a custom annotation a Validator associated with it (*for more information refer to the [documentation - Configuring Custom Constraints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints)*):

> Each bean validation constraint consists of two parts:
>
> - A `@Constraint` annotation that declares the constraint and its configurable properties.
> - An implementation of the `jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator` interface that implements the constraint’s behavior.

We can find more information regarding the requirements for the custom annotation in the [Bean validation documentation `Constraint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Constraint.html):

> Each constraint annotation must host the following attributes:
>
> - `String message() default [...];` which should default to an error
>   message key made of the fully-qualified class name of the constraint
>   followed by `.message`. For example
>   `"{com.acme.constraints.NotSafe.message}"`
> - `Class<?>[] groups() default {};` for user to customize the targeted groups
> - `Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};` for extensibility purposes

So our custom annotation needs to have at least these three attributes, and we're interested primarily in the first one, providing a message which would be used in case if an exception occurs. Let's our annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = EngineTypeValidator.class)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EngineTypeConstraint {
    String message() default "Engine type does not exist";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator should implement generic interface [`ConstraintValidator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html), specifying the associated annotation and the validated type as its parameters.

That's how the implementation might look like:

```
public class EngineTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EngineTypeConstraint, String> {
    
    private static final Set<String> TYPE_NAMES =
        EnumSet.allOf(EngineType.class).stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String engineType,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        
        if (!TYPE_NAMES.contains(engineType)) throw new EngineTypeNotValidException(engineType);
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you have probably noticed, validator throws a custom exception `EngineTypeNotValidException` which receives an invalid engine model as a parameter. We need this exception in order to build a response based on it.

```
public class EngineTypeNotValidException extends RuntimeException {
    
    public EngineTypeNotValidException(String type) {
        super(String.format("Engine type '%s' doesn't exist.", type));
    }
}
```

To handle this exception and produces an error-response by using [Controller Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice). For that, we need to define a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and create a method marked with `@ExceptionHandler` to target the custom exception defined above.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = MyDetailsController.class)
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(EngineTypeNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInvalidEngine(RuntimeException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        return ResponseEntity
            .badRequest()
            .body(new ErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase(),
                List.of(cause.getMessage())
            ));
    }
}
```

Finally, to customize the response body, we can create a POJO with a couple of string field for representing the information of a failing response.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class ErrorResponse {
    private int status;
    private String message;
    private List<String> errors;
}
```

## Demo

That's it now we can give it a try.

Consider the following dummy Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyDetailsController {
    
    @PostMapping("/newMyDetails")
    public String newCar(@RequestBody @Valid MyDetailsDto dto) {
        // some business logic
        return "is valid";
    }
}
```

And here's a couple screenshots from Postman with responses:

- ***Valid request** (hard-coded message from the Controller in the response):*

[image]

- ***Invalid request** (response with a customized error message, prompting that enum-name provided in the request doesn't exist):*

[image]